# Cannot produce single project jar file (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, executable-jar, packaging

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-postgresql-docker) tutorial for Docker and postgres with Spring boot in order to create a docker container, but I cannot create a single project jar file. App runs fine with maven and intellij, just cant package it.

My project is as follows 3 modules each with pom.xml, and one parent pom.xml to organize them. `@SpringBootApplication` is only one and exists only on the module where also the build with maven is located.

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

An overview of the pom.xml files

parent

```
<?xml version....>
<project....>

    <groupId>eu.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myProject</name>


    <properties>
.....
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>

    <modules>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>web</module>
        <module>key</module>
  </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

</project>
```

core

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project... >
  <parent>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <groupId>eu.company</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>core</artifactId>

  <dependencies>
... jpa, h2, etc etc
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

web (where the @SpringBootApplication exists)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project....>
  <parent>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <groupId>eu.company</groupId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <artifactId>web</artifactId>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>eu.company</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>eu.company</groupId>
      <artifactId>key</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
......
etc etc 
  </dependencies>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak-bom.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

The files produced are only 3 jars for each submodule, but no parent.
The same happens if I run from maven inside intellij, mvn installed, mvnw.

```
  find . -name '*.jar'
./.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar
./core/target/core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
./key/target/key-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
./web/target/web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

What am I missing here ??

If you need some extra info or code just comment so I can edit.

Answer (score 2):

In the parent, you have specified

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

That means that the primary artifact will not be a jar, but the pom.xml itself.

When working with submodules, the parent module will not generate a jar, since the packaging is supposed to be a pom.

Comment: at the tutorial i posted, there is also code on github, the package is pom. I saw also in other guides that when using multi modules the parent should be pom. Am I wrong ? When I replace with jar, i cannot compile. guide code sample here https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/docker/pom.xml

Comment: I get the error :   [ERROR] 'packaging' with value 'jar' is invalid. Aggregator projects require 'pom' as packaging. @ line 36, column 13
 @

Comment: hey in your case, your submodules generate the required jars/docker images. The parent should not generate any as it is simply a parent pom where you define common dependenices, plugins for the children projects where the actual logic goes

Comment: This: `the parent module should not generate a jar.` is simply wrong. They can not generate a jar at all because they have to have packaging: `pom` so no code will even being compiled nor packaged...

Comment: @khmarbaise you are right, I edited the answer

Comment: ok interesting, so how do i dockerize with submodules ? Probably this should be my question...

Comment: @khmarbaise I managed to build a single jar plugin that runs  using this guide, using the maven-jar-plugin and the maven-dependency-plugin 
https://medium.com/holisticon-consultants/dont-build-fat-jars-for-docker-applications-6252a5571248
Is this approach correct ?